# Find $x_{1}$ such that $x_n$ is convergent $x_{n+1}=(n+1)x_n -1,$ $\forall n \in N^{*}, n\ge 1$

Tags: real-analysis, recurrence-relations

Let $x_n$ be a sequence of real numbers such that $x_{n+1}=(n+1)x_n -1,$  $\forall n \in N^{*}, n\ge 1$ .Find $x_1$ such that  $x_n$ converges.
$\text {My attempt: }$
The only way that i tried to use was to write $$y_n=nx_n,\text{ and obtain that }y_{n+1}-y_n=(n^2+n+1)\frac{y_n}{n}-n-1, \text {So, it s similar to }
 y_{n+1}+\alpha_n y_n=\beta_n$$
So, we can find the general solution of the homogeneous associated recurrence

$$ y_{j+1}+\alpha_j y_j=0.
\forall  j \in N^{*} \text { We get that } 
y_{n+1}=(-1)^n \prod_{j=1}^{n}\alpha_j y_1 $$
$\text {That is where i could not continue anymore }$

Comment: Please show your attempt.

Comment: The value of $x_1$ does not predict any thing about convergence of a sequence. In fact, neither do the first finite number of terms. So, why is this sequence special ?

Comment: @Medo, what are you talking about??

Comment: $x_2=2x_1 +1$, $x_4=24x_1-17$ so for arbitrary $n$ we have something like this $x_n=n!x_1-S(n)$ where $S$ depends on $n$ and goes to infinity "slower than" $n!$

Comment: So slightly more than 17/24 then.

Comment: @Empy2: $e-2$, to be more precise.

Comment: @TonyK, how to get that constant? I ve posted what i tried

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We have
$$x_n=n!\,x_1-u_n$$
for the sequence $(u_n)=(0,1,4,17,86,\ldots)$ defined by $u_1=0$ and $u_{n+1}=(n+1)u_n+1$.

Now define the sequence $(v_n)$ by $v_n=u_n/n!$ Then we can rearrange $u_{n+1}=(n+1)u_n+1$ to get $v_{n+1}=v_n+1/(n+1)!$ So $(v_n)$ looks like:
$$\left(0,\;\;\frac{1}{2!},\;\;\frac{1}{2!}+\frac{1}{3!},\;\;\frac{1}{2!}+\frac{1}{3!}+\frac{1}{4!},\;\;\frac{1}{2!}+\frac{1}{3!}+\frac{1}{4!}+\frac{1}{5!},\;\ldots\right)$$
which tends to $e-2$.

Also, we have $x_n=n!x_1-u_n=n!(x_1-v_n)$.

What this tells us is that $(x_n)$ certainly doesn't converge unless $x_1=e-2$. But this doesn't necessarily mean that ($x_n)$ converges, because there is a factor of $n!$ that might throw things off. You have to show that it converges by estimating the error term $n!(v_n-(e-2))$, which you should try to show tends to $0$ (it's not too hard).